# Disable self registration

Tags: google-identity-toolkit, google-identity

I'm trying to disable user self-registration in Google Identity Toolkit, or limit the emails that can register comparing them in a database I have. Is it possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to impose the limitation on the front end, you'd probably have to interact directly with the API (https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/web/reference/). If you're using one of the Identity Toolkit libraries, you could also just let people authenticate as normal, but only allow them to complete the registration on your site if the email matches one on the list.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking about the second one, it's easier to implement.